# Python AST : Insert argument to class

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Using AST to add argument to the existing class. In the AST world, it is classdef which I already found, how do I add an argument to that classDef or update the bases basically ?

From

```
class testApp:
```

To

```
class testApp(Core):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Python 3.9 you have `ast.unparse` available, which allows you to do this:

```
import ast
ast_obj = ast.parse("class testApp:\n  pass")
ast_obj.body[0].bases.append(ast.Name(id='Core'))
print(ast.unparse(ast_obj))
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @bbayles. 

Unfortunately I am on Python 3.7, is it possible to do with Python 3.7 ?

Comment: your answer got me in the right direction. Thank you  bbayles

Comment: @shaileshgavathe You can backport `ast.unparse` to 3.7 by just copying the source. Some minor changes might be necessary